# change descriptor when renaming file linux

Tags: linux, rename

I got a process in CentOS which writes its log to a file. When I rename it, it still writes to it. Is there a way to change that file descriptor without restarting the process?

Comment: No. Write to a pipe, use a log rotating utility on the other end of the pipe.

Comment: Or restart the daemon process. Some programs accept `SIGHUP` signal to reopen log files.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, it seem reasonable, but as I am a quite beginner in matters of linux, can you provide some reference to a good tutorial?

Comment: You can use e.g. [`rotatelogs` from Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html). In order to pipe output to `rotatelogs` you may have to create a named pipe. Something like `mkfifo mypipe; rotatelogs logfile 3600 < mypipe; myprocess -logfile mypipe`. Or, if your process writes to the standard output, just `myprocess | rotatelogs ...`, no named pipe.